# Ubuntu 14.04.4 Freezing Frequently

Tags: 14.04, freeze

First of all I'm not an Expert in Ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my Dell Inspiron 11 3147. Since Ubuntu 14.04.4 Released, it's freezing frequently. Especially when I'm Browsing the Internet (I'm currently using Opera but I tried Chrome and Firefox too). It was okay when I was using 14.04.3. But the Latest Version is totally Freezing my Laptop (Even Mouse doesn't work). I tried Magic SysRq Key Combination (Alt + SysRq + REISUB) but nothing happens. What can I do to fix this Problem?

Thank You!

P.S. I fresh installed 14.04.4 when it Released. And the Same thing happens on Ubuntu 15.10 too.

Edit: Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 064d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Edit 2: Output of `free --human` :

```
    abdullah@abdullah-Inspiron-11-3147:~$ free --human
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:          3.7G       425M       3.3G        44M        23M       190M
    -/+ buffers/cache:       211M       3.5G
    Swap:         1.9G         0B       1.9G
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Edited my Question

Comment: I've never got an acceptance for my answer while 2 other people thought my answer was valuable...  Any problems with my answer???  **:-(**

Answer (score 1):

An Atom processor?  Running Ubuntu???  **:O**

I'd start looking at [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and install *that!*

Probably your system was *just barely* fitting until 14.04.4 when it started swapping like mad and that just *looks* like it's freezing: it's actually still working, but 1000 times slower then before...

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*

<sub>**Alternatively,** just get rid of that thing and buy a new computer instead of using Lubuntu (which I've ran on Atom processors a long time ago, though not recently)</sub>

Comment: Other laptops are bulky to Carry, that's why I use this laptop. And Windows 10 runs just fine on this laptop. Ubuntu also runs good just the Freezing problem. But now, it's freezing much less than before.

Another thing, My Laptop has actually a Pentium Processor but it's showing Atom, I don't know why.

BTW, thank you for your comment.

Comment: If you could: leave the machine for about 15 minutes next time it "freezes" and then try to [run the command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/740173/how-do-i-run-a-command) `free --human` and post the output into your question, I can prove this to you!  (or try Lubuntu from a DVD/USB stick and see if it happens there too) Oh and if this answer did help, just click the little grey ☑ at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Installed Xubuntu. Same thing is Happening.

Comment: I didn't say Xubuntu: I said Lubuntu...

Comment: I don't like the interface of LXDE. That's why I installed Xubuntu. Maybe I'll just wait for 16.04.

Comment: 16.04 is going to make things even worse... What's the output of `free --human`?  Maybe there's a workaround...

Comment: Added the output of `free --human` in the Post.

Another thing, I've tried openSUSE Leap, Majaro. Didn't face anything like I'm facing in Ubuntu.

Comment: Weird...  Is that the `free --human` after just booting without any applications open or is that just before it freezes?  if the latter: Does this happen in the guest session too???

Comment: Didn't try it in Guest Session. Freezes happen Randomly, so there's no way to take a `free --human` output just before a freeze. It's an output after using some apps like Firefox, File Manager etc. The OS freezes mainly when a Browser is open or I'm browsing the Internet. 


And another thing, because of this freezing I thought of monitoring the CPU and RAM usage all time. So I installed `Indicator-SysMonitor`. I saw the usage after a freeze and it was pretty normal. CPU was at 2-3% and RAM was around 19%. I did this a while back in Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your user profile: try it out in the guest session and feed back please (grasping at straws now)

Comment: Problem with my User Profile could be once but Multiple times? I don't think so. I have Re-installed Ubuntu (or Lubuntu, Xubuntu) a lot of times and the problem is there every single time. I'm tired of this. I've just Installed Linux Mint 17.3. Let's see how this one goes. Hope I'll not face the same problem here (as Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu). And thank you for your comments.

Comment: If you re-installed multiple times, and still had the same problem multiple times, it looks like a user profile problem.  Unfortunately, Linux Mint is off-topic here, so I cannot help you any further.