# How do I run a command?

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I am a new user, who has just been told to run / execute a command. The answer has some text with a grey background like `this text here` or

```
sometimes this text here.
```

However, I don't know what "run" or "command" means in relation to Ubuntu.

How do I do this?

---

<sup>This is intended for use as a Q&A you can link to when you tell someone to run a command.</sup>

Comment: Hmm downvote because we don't need this? Or newbie questions are discouraged? Or this is a duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it)

Comment: The run dialog is pretty limited - for a lot of commands, you do need a terminal to be opened.

Comment: Eh.. How do you run a command? A: Use a terminal. Then: What is a terminal, etc.? It follows trivially.

Comment: It's so related that, for me, it's a dupe. My vote stands.

Comment: -1: because the run dialog is only useful if a) you don't need the output, and b) you don't need to provide input.

Comment: You're going to say that to a new user who's so unfamiliar with these concepts that they don't even understand what a command is? Good luck explaining input, output, authorization for `sudo` commands, etc. to them. This is one question I certainly won't be linking to.

Comment: @muru no. This is a question that is simply saying how to run a command... I thought that we were here to help people new to Ubuntu too, no? Why the angst towards people who don't know things? I think the answer clearly explains that it's good for launching a GUI program...

Comment: So I, who am not posting misleading things, am the angsty one? All right then. As I said, my vote stands. Good day.

Comment: As I said before: The run dialog is only useful if you don't need input or output. And since you claim so boldly that you don't need a terminal, thus implying you don't need either of these, you are misleading new users. Good luck getting a user to run `sudo apt-get update` from the run dialog. That's all I have to say.

Comment: Excellent!  Favourited, bookmarked and bounty added!!!  ;-)

Comment: Using it as well!  http://askubuntu.com/a/746248/344926

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### What is a command?

Commands, and the command line, are another way to tell the computer what to do. For example, you can click the google chrome icon, or you can run the command `google-chrome`.

This may seem a silly thing to do, but when you click the icon, that's what the computer does! It also is much easier to do some tasks with the command line.

For example, installing programs can be quicker and easier - just use `sudo apt-get install program`, rather than navigating through the software center.

And if my Bluetooth stops working, I run a command to fix it - that's the only way!

#### Anyway, how do you run a command?

This is also simple, although there are many ways to do it.

Simply, you [open a Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and type (or copy / paste) the command in, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the image, I've run the command `ls Desktop/` which will list all files on my desktop. Note that to paste you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *<kbd>Shift</kbd>* + <kbd>V</kbd> in the terminal.

[image]

By default you open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, or opening the Dash and searching for "Terminal".

#### What is a `tty`?

Sometimes, you may be told to run a command in the `tty` - often followed by a number, for example `tty2`. The GUI runs on `tty7`. (Update for 2021: the GUI now often runs on `tty1` or `tty2`).

To access this, you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>FX</kbd> - where <kbd>FX</kbd> is replaced with the Function key that corresponds to the number. For example, to access `tty2` you would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

You have to login to this, but some things need the `tty` to work.

Getting back to the GUI will depend on your Ubuntu version, but trying each `tty` in turn should work until you find it. If you can’t find it on any `tyy` 1-8, you may need to restart - but ask the person who is helping you by commenting below the answer!

#### What about GUI (Graphical User Interface) programs?

The terminal can also launch GUI programs. This can have the advantage of viewing the output the program gives - for example running `software-centre` looks like this:

[image]

You can also provide extra "arguments" - also known as "parameters" and "options" to the command.

For example, if I run `google-chrome --app=http://youtube.com` it opens a window without the URL bar or the tabs:

[image]

Bear in mind, if you close the terminal, you also lose the Google Chrome window...

#### One final method

This is **only good for GUI programs**, like Chrome, Firefox and Gedit. However, it also means you don't have a terminal lying around - which you could accidentally close. It's no good for `sudo apt-get install program` or similar, because you can't type your password after running it.

Press Alt + F2, and a "Run Dialouge" appears - a bit like the run window on Windows:

Ubuntu:                                                                                    Windows:

[image][image]

You can type any command into here, and it will run it!

Comment: FN is easy to confuse with laptop key Fn. I'd rather provide a concrete example instead, like F2 for tty2. Also, I may have overseen, but I've not found where you mention how to go back to X from the VT. If a user is really a newbie as you suppose in the question, then they must learn how to go back to "warm and safe" GUI.

Comment: @Tim I would suggest you to put a warning on your *What is a tty?* paragraph explaining how to come back to the GUI **before** explaining how to access ttx: some people (e.g. younger I) do not read explanations until the end of the paragraph but rather directly try commands... and stays blocked on command-line mode!

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question.  Too lengthy.

Comment: @mbiber This answered *my* question pretty well. If you have any specific suggestions as to where it could be cut down, please say. I think I managed to condense a lot of information pretty well - but if it could be better I'm happy to listen :)

Comment: @Tim If someone wanted to "read up" then first result in Google (first 10 results for that matter) are hefty peaces of text. For example https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal. I am very satisfied with this answer, that's why I gave it +1, but I expect complete noobs would require an answer for this question to be short and to the point. Too much information is often of-putting to non technical users! I'll add an answer I would have expected when I was a complete noob with Ubuntu.

Comment: @mbiber that seems sensible, I doubt I can cut down the answer without taking away quite a lot for it to still make sense. Another answer could be much better.

Comment: In recent Ubuntu versions, GUI no more runs on tty7, but on lower numbered ttys. Usually the login screen is on tty1, and the actual GNOME session on tty2. Ttys from 3 up are free to use.

Comment: @raj yes, thanks for the reminder. Updated.

Comment: @Tim? Thank you very much. For the last point, the one that uses `Alt + F2`, most of commands are unknown to it. I keep getting `Command not found`. For example none of my aliases are there.

Answer (score 3):

Types of commands vary somewhat. They can be single line, like

```
 echo 'HelloAskubuntu' # Print 'HelloAskubuntu'
```

single line with redirection to other commands

```
echo 'Hello World' | wc # count number of lines, words, and chars in 'Hello World'
```

multiline with redirection

```
$> bash << END                                                                 
> echo one
> echo two
> echo three
> END
one
two
three
```

Or multiline in form of scripts (which in terms of Windows language is batch  files).  Scripts are just files with lists of commands in them, that are executed sequentially. These are effectively custom build programs/software, analogous to building your own electronics out of existing spare parts.

Regardless of the type of command, you will need access to a command line, commonly known as `Terminal`. There is either TTY terminals on Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] keyboard shortcuts (exit those with Alt+F7), or you can use GUI app by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T.

Terminals typically run software known as `shell`. The shell interprets the commands and executes them. Some shells are compatible with each other for the most part like `bash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `zsh` , while `tcsh` and `csh` are quite different. They all have different features, and often are used for different tasks.

Either a script or a command have to be executed in shell. Some commands are physically present executable files on disks, like `/bin/ls`. Other commands are `aliases` or `functions` that are lists of existing commands. They exist only in the settings of the shell. For example, for bash it would be `.bashrc` settings file. Real executables can be run with the name or full path, like `ls` or `/bin/ls` respectivelly.

Scripts can be run with full path, or if they are stored somewhere that your shell knows about ( and it knows about only things in the `PATH` variable, which you can read with `echo $PATH` ). For example, I can run my script by going to my bin directory and running it with `./` operator, like so

```
 cd $HOME/bin; ./helloworld.sh
```

Or give terminal full path

```
 /home/Serg/bin/helloworld.sh
```

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question. Too lengthy.

Comment: I can add tldr at the top

Answer (score 3):

To run a command you need to open a **terminal** window. You can find the terminal among your applications like you would any other. Copy and paste the grayed text into the terminal window after opening it and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to execute. You will probably see some text output during and after execution. This is feedback from the command you just ran.

**Command** is an instruction you give to a computer - you tell it to do something. You are already familiar with some commands, you use them while using your computer all the time. For example clicking on buttons in your GUI (graphical user interface), like web browsers, is the same thing - telling your computer to do something.

If you require more information you can find it at 
[What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal