# Ubuntu backup using bash commands/command line

Tags: backup, chmod

So i accidentally run the command:

`sudo chmod -R 2777 /`

Wenever i login, it would only bring up the bash command line interface.
Now how can i backup my system using only bash commands?

i have tried some post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1422712

`sudo tar cvpzf ../../home/$backupUser/backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys --exclude=/media /`

but requires `sudo`, which i can't do right now.

Comment: Success with the back-up.  Restoring is just drag and drop of the directories you need after you reinstall your system.  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks :) but i tried your method on on a live USB and it worked. i'm using ubuntu server 14.04 btw, so no drag and drop for me.

Comment: **:D**  Just a reversal of the `cp` then!  **;-)**  *You're welcome!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert an external HDD formatted on another machine using FAT if none of your files are >4GB and [type the following command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740173/how-do-i-run-a-command):

```
ls /media/$USER
```

That will give you a list of names one of which is your hard drive.  Then copy the files over by issuing:

```
cp --verbose /home/$USER/* /media/$USER/NameOfHDD
```

Where you substitute `NameOfHDD` for the name you found previously (I cannot tell you which: it depends on the HDD itself and how it was formatted)

And then you wait until it finishes...

**To restore** just type:

```
cp --verbose /media/$USER/NameOfHDD/* /Home/$USER/
```

(if both user names before and after re-install are the same!)