# 403 Forbidden you dont have permission

Tags: bash

i want to install steam in my computer ubuntu 14.04 when i install steam its says that forbidden 403 how can i fix ???? HELP

it says that
You don't have permission to access /steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at repo.steamstatic.com Port 80
i dont know what is this !!!
i'm new user i ubuntu

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the Steam website - not Ubuntu. Ask at the Steam Forum.

Comment: but when i install steam when it open in steam.exe it says could not be open

Comment: when i open it with archive manager its says that "An Error Occurred while loading the archive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what command you are using to install.

Comment: You have written steam.exe ?? I'm not sure you downloaded the right package ubuntu can't install .exe by default. The package management is not the same as Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install Steam using [a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740173/how-do-i-run-a-command):

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Then you can run Steam from the Dash:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/753054/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)** (and +1 as it is now a good answer!)