# Ubuntu 14.04 unable to establish Ethernet or WiFi connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, ethernet, troubleshooting

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot with Windows 7 on separate HDD. I went through several threads regarding connection problems but I didn't understand them much as I have never used Linux in the past. Ubuntu detects that Ethernet cable is plugged in but it can't establish a connection.

**`ifconfig`:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:ad:81:b8  
      inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fead:81b8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:64 (64.0 B)  TX bytes:5088 (5.0 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:7184 (7.1 KB)  TX bytes:7184 (7.1 KB)
```

**`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:**

```
s Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:855c]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

---

I tried to follow the post which got 186 up vote in the thread below but unfortunately in step 2 it wants user to be connected to internet in some form, so I am unsure what should I do to proceed as I can only connect to internet on Windows 7.
    [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

This didn't work.
    [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653)

Comment: Please Open Terminal `(Ctrl + Alt + T)` and post the output of ifconfig

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please [edit] your question and add the output of the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` [command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/740173/how-do-i-run-a-command).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Or look art the off-line guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653

Answer (score 0):

Do you have static IP Configuration? If yes then in the connection settings edit the wired connection or something like that to have those settings and try connecting.